# How to make babel compile null coalescing operator?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

A dependency of mine uses the null coalescing operator. Babel can't handle it. Is there any way to make Babel work here?

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/transform-runtime',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'
    ],
};
```

Compile error:

```
./node_modules/test/dist/test.js 26:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:10)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export class Test {
|   constructor() {
>     null ?? 0;
|   }
|
```

Comment: Same did not find a solution